# GDAL Intersects() not working as it should?

Tags: gdal, ogr, topology, intersect

Doing a topological analysis in GDAL/OGR returned an unexpected result. When I started investigating, it seems possible that the Intersects() method is badly implemented. Specifically, points along a polygon's boundary returns False, when it should return True:

```
from osgeo import ogr

poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(0, 0)
ring.AddPoint(5, 5)
ring.AddPoint(10, 0)
ring.CloseRings()
poly.AddGeometry(ring)

point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(10, 0)

poly.Intersects(point)
>>> False
poly.Disjoint(point)
>>> False
```

Not only does the point correctly intersect the polygon, Intersects and Disjoint should be opposite subsets, and never return the same value. Furthermore, the Intersection() method, which should only work when geometries intersect, works normally:

```
inter = poly.Intersection(point)
inter.ExportToWkt()
>>> 'POINT (10 0 0)'
```

I'd like to know if perhaps I'm not understanding this correctly, or if my GDAL compilation is problematic, or if it's GDAL itself that has a bug.

Info: GDAL 2.2.1 64-bits, Tamas Szekeres' VS2008 version.

Comment: This feels pretty much like a bug. With POINT (10, 0) `poly.Touches(point)` returns true, as well as `poly.Intersects(point)` if the point is (5, 1). Write a mail to gdal-devel mailing list and report this.

Comment: It is a bug of the version. My old GDAL 1.10.1 for your code returns True

Comment: Thanks nadya. As user30184 suggested, I have raised this issue in the mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed per GDAL ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7091